# SQL SELECT statement doesn't work in php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram php bot and I've got this problem with sql select statement which is not working.

here is the script:

```
$chat_id = $update->message->chat->id;

$check_user = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE chat_id='".$chat_id."'");
if($check_user->rowCount() > 0){

  $user_data = $check_user->fetchAll();
  $user_status = 'active user';
}else{
  $user_status = 'new';
}
```

chat id is an integer var which I get from user profile and check if it exists in database or not; but no matter what, it always sets the user_status to 'new' even if that chat id already exists in the database.


we store username in the database too(which is string) so I launched this very SQL SELECT with username and it worked!

what's the problem?

update: I just tried 'mysqli' and unfortunately I get the same result.

Comment: This is mysql right?

Comment: @bassxzero `fetchall()`->PDO I think

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile PDO is a wrapper for many database engines.

Comment: @bassxzero oh you asking the DBMS I thought u were asking the API used

Comment: You get an error, no results, or what happens with this code?

Comment: No error. just as I said it sets user status to 'new'; which probably means rowCount is equal to 0

Comment: @HamidR did u check the answers below?

Comment: @masivuye-cokile yes I did

Answer (score 1):

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use
>   PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
>   predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) if you want to know more

*If chat_id is integer you should remove single quotes from your query

```
$chat_id = $update->message->chat->id;

$check_user = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE chat_id = $chat_id");
if($check_user->fetchColumn() > 0){

  $user_data = $check_user->fetchAll();
  $user_status = 'active user';
}else{
  $user_status = 'new';
}
```

Comment: That would not make a difference.

Comment: If this is mysql then it will cast `'1'`(string) to `1`(int). So it would not make a difference.

Comment: I still get the same result !

Comment: @HamidR remove the where part and check if you get more than one row

Comment: @edisoni-1337 I checked it and i get the right result, also I checked it with WHERE username=$username and it worked too

Comment: so there are two things to check then : 1) check if you have a column chat_id and 2) check the value of $chat_id and check if you have any record in your database with that value

Answer (score 1):

[rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

So rowCount() is not really reliable with a select statement, I would suggest that you do your select then use PDOStatement::fetchAll which will return  array containing all of the result set rows, then count the array if its greater than zero set your status.

```
<?php
$chat_id = $update->message->chat->id;

$check_user = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE chat_id = ? ");
$check_user->execute([$chat_id]);
$user_data = $check_user->fetchAll();

if (count($user_data) > 0) {

    $user_status = 'active user';
}else{

    $user_status = 'new';
}
```

Comment: still the same result !!

Comment: @HamidR are u sure u have that ID?

Comment: Yeah I can print it, and I've used it multiple times in the script

Comment: @HamidR can you run the query and hardcode the id and see?

Comment: I didn't have enough time to wait so I changed the whole code in order to fix that part:))) anyway thanks for helping bro

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes and the dots from you id

```
 $check_user = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE chat_id='$chat_id'");
```

Comment: If this is mysql then it will cast `'1'`(string) to `1`(int). So it would not make a difference.

Comment: It doesn't make any change bro